# How to extend an existing eclipse plugin functionality

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, plugins

We are using tomcat plugin for eclipse and there is a button on the toolbar which starts the tomcat. I would like to add additional functionality to be performed on the button click before the tomcat start.

I extracted the tomcat plugin files and check which class is handling the button action. It is

```
net.sf.eclipse.tomcat.actions.StartActionDelegate
```

I have tried to create a new plugin and assign StartActionDelegate from tomcat plugin to my button (just to check if i can call the action from other plugin). Doesn't work. Throws NoClassDefFoundError.

Any other ideas?